# Docker Persistent Storage from another Disk: Does it consume space from both disks?

Tags: docker, persistent-storage

I have 2 devices on my Linux machine, `/dev/sda` (This is where docker is installed) and `/dev/sdc` (This is a 2TB storage device). I'm planning to create a web app that will run on a `php-fpm` container. On the web app, the user will be allowed to upload multiples files. What I want to achieve is the files that will be uploaded by the user will be placed on the 2TB storage device (`/dev/sdc`).

I mounted `/dev/sdc` device to `/mnt/sdc/` folder and I created an `uploads` folder inside `/mnt/sdc`. I modified my `docker-compose` file to volume `/mnt/sdc/uploads` inside the `php-fpm` container. This is basically how it goes:

[image: architechture]
  .

When the user uploads files, it will be placed on the `uploads` folder inside the `php-fpm` container, and also it will be placed on `/mnt/sdc/uploads` folder. But I want to know what storage space will be used on this setup. Will the files uploaded on the website consume space on both `/dev/sda` and `/dev/sdc`? Or will it consume space on `/dev/sdc` only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `docker-compose.yml` file says something like

```
volumes:
  - "/mnt/sdc/uploads:/uploads"
```

then writes inside the container to the `/uploads` directory go directly to the other mounted drive; they do not take up space in the host `/var/lib/docker` or have any other presence in the container filesystem.  (Internally it is a **mount**(2) call and works the same way as `/mnt` being on your root disk but `/mnt/sdc` being the other disk.)

Comment: Thanks! I thought it still takes up space from the host. It was a big help ;)